# How set background of row dynamic using flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

Look my source:

- Template:

[code]

```
<mx:Script source="ListStatus.as" />

<!-- Template -->
<mx:DataGrid id="grid" width="100%" height="100%" doubleClick="editRecord();">
    <mx:columns  >
        <mx:DataGridColumn width="30" resizable="false" draggable="false">
            <mx:itemRenderer>
                <mx:Component>
                    <mx:LinkButton icon="@Embed('assets/img/delete.png')" click="outerDocument.deleteRecord(event);" />
                </mx:Component>
            </mx:itemRenderer>
        </mx:DataGridColumn>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Nome" dataField="name" />
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Nome de exibição" dataField="displayName" />
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Cor" dataField="color" />            
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

[/code]

- ActionScript:

[code]
import fuel.Ajax;
import fuel.IModule;
import fuel.window.Window;

import mx.controls.Alert;
import mx.events.ModuleEvent;
import mx.modules.ModuleLoader;

public var win:Window;

/**
 * Constructor
 * 
 * Get data from turbo gears controller
 */
public function init():void
{
    showLoading();
    Ajax.requestJSON('/access/status/getList', {}, function (obj:Object):void {
        hideLoading();
        grid.dataProvider = obj.results;
    }); 
}

/**
 * Call form to edit record
 */
public function editRecord():void
{

```
try {
    grid.selectedItem.id;                   
} catch(e:Error) {
    Alert.show("Você deve selecionar um registro válido", "Atenção");
    return;
}

var module:ModuleLoader = new ModuleLoader();
module.url = "access/CreateStatus.swf";
module.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;
module.addEventListener( ModuleEvent.READY, onModuleReady );

var title_bar:String = "Edição de Status (" + grid.selectedItem.id + ")";

if( this.window ){
    win = this.window.openChild(title_bar, module, 410, 250);
} else {
    win = (parentApplication as Admin).winManager.openWindow(title_bar, module, 410, 250);
}
```

}

/**
 * Call controller to delete record
 */
private function actionDeleteRecord( resp:Object ):void
{
    if( resp.detail == Alert.YES ){
        grid.enabled = false;

```
    Ajax.requestJSON( "/access/status/delete", { 'id' : grid.selectedItem.id }, function( obj:Object ):void {
        if (obj.error == false) {
            Alert.show("Registro deletado com sucesso", "Confirmação");
        } else {
            Alert.show(obj.msg, "Erro");
        }

        init();             
    });

    grid.enabled = true;
}
```

}

/**
 * Call request to delete record
 */
public function deleteRecord( event : Event ):void
{
    Alert.show("Esta operação NÃO poderá ser desfeita.\nDeseja mesmo remover o status \""+grid.selectedItem.displayName+"\"?", "Confirmação", Alert.YES | Alert.NO, this, actionDeleteRecord );
}

public function onModuleReady( event:ModuleEvent ):void
{
    var loader:ModuleLoader = event.target as ModuleLoader;

```
var m:* = loader.child as IModule;
if( m ) m.addEventListener( Event.RENDER, function runModule(e:Event):void{
    m.setId(grid.selectedItem.id);
    m.window = win;                 
    m.removeEventListener( Event.RENDER, runModule );
});
```

};
[/code]

I need set background of row using the value of color how exists in dataProvider.

Sorry for my ignorance, this is my first project using flex.

Thank's!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to make a class that extends DataGrid and override the drawRowBackground method, which is responsible for drawing a colored rectangle behind the row items.

[The drawRowBackground method](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/DataGrid.html#drawRowBackground%28%29) is passed a default color, as well as the index of your current data item, so you can retrieve the current item, grab a custom color property from it, and pass that color into the super.drawRowBackground() call.

```
override protected function drawRowBackground(s:Sprite, rowIndex:int, 
                                                y:Number, height:Number,
                                                color:uint, dataIndex:int):void 
{
    if (dataIndex < dataProvider.length && dataProvider[dataIndex])
    {
        color = dataProvider[dataIndex].color;
    }
    super.drawRowBackground(s, rowIndex, y, height, color, dataIndex);
}
```